# SQL date Filter | Model Performace

Tags: mysql, sql, date

We have to split the data into train and test sets and calculate the True positive rate metric in SQL. We have the data until ID 1000, Below is the sample table _score

| ID | _date | prediction | actual |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-02-01 | 0.81 | 1 |
| 2 | 2020-05-04 | 0.22 | 0 |
| 3 | 2020-01-18 | 0.84 | 1 |
| 4 | 2020-07-11 | 0.92 | 1 |
| 5 | 2020-12-31 | 0.44 | 0 |
| 6 | 2020-06-02 | 0.71 | 1 |
| 7 | 2020-03-02 | 0.11 | 0 |
| 1000 | 2020-11-22 | 0.61 | 0 |

Question:

- > let _date before 2020-11-01 as our training period, and
  > the date after that as the test period. Calculate the positive rate in these two date range

Formula: positive rate = number of positive / (number of positive + number of negative)

Positive  = 1 and negative = 0

Please help with calculating the TPR rate in a single query, I am confused about filtering these records in train and test set.

Expected Output:

| ID | label | Positive Rate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Training Data | X |
| 2 | Test Data | Y |

We need the Positive rate column for both train and test set data in a single column, which we have to split upon the date value as mentioned above. We will have only 2 rows, one for training set and other for the test set.

Train data : Date is before 2020-11-01
Test data : Date after 2020-11-01

- Request to comment if any edits or clarifying questions is required.

Comment: I’m not sure I understand your expected output table - shouldn't you just have 2 rows, one for Train data and one for Test data? If not, how are you selecting the dates showing in your output table and how are you calculating values for those dates? Your question states you are calculating for 2 different periods of time (before 2020-11-01 and after), not for individual dates

Comment: Yes, you are right, my apologies for not understanding the question correctly. I have made the edits, can you please help me with the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can do it like this fist you create a subselect, that sorts the data for the id and label and count the positives and negartives.

Then you use the sunbquery to get your wanted data

> ```
> SELECT `ID`,`Label`, SUM(positive) * 1.0/ (SUM(positive)+SUM(negative))
> FROM
> (SELECT 
>     IF(`_date` <= '2020-11-01',1,2) AS 'ID',
>     IF(`_date` <= '2020-11-01','Training Data','Test Data') AS 'Label',
>     IF(`actual` = 1,1,0) as positive ,
>     IF(`actual` = 0,1,0) as negative 
> FROM predictions) pred
> GROUP BY `ID`,`Label`
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | Label         | SUM(positive) * 1.0/ (SUM(positive)+SUM(negative))
> -: | :------------ | -------------------------------------------------:
>  1 | Training Data |                                            0.66667
>  2 | Test Data     |                                            0.00000
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8569137bbfcd37f6d22883fa8092e45f)*